# Tag article-writing

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

The tags [article-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article-writing) and [publishing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) seem a bit too close in terms of applicable content in my opinion to warrant being separate. Should we merge the tags or just get rid of the article-writing one altogether?

Answer (score 6):

To me the two tags seem to be sufficiently different.

The tag [article-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article-writing) is, of course, about writing articles. It mainly contains questions on English language (some phrases and grammatical constructions are more prevalent in technical writing), presentation (What to put into introduction? How much details and preliminaries to include?), style.

The tag [publishing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) has similar focus; but it is about a different part of getting something published. Namely the process of submitting a paper, communicating with editors and similar stuff. Here I would typically expect questions like: Where to publish? Is this publishable in the scientific journal? How important is number of publications in my career?

I do not claim that the two tags are always used in the manner I described. But I have tried to describe very briefly the way I understand these two tags. When I look at the first page of questions tagged with these tags, I'd say that they are used *in most cases* approximately in this way.

Now that we have [academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions) (which is in beta, but seems to be [doing well](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia)), perhaps some of the questions of this type could be asked there. MSE is, in my opinion, preferable only for questions which are specific to publishing mathematical contents. If the same question is valid for any scientific area and the answer is not going to be dependent on the scientific discipline, academia.SE would be my preferred choice. Here is also an older discussion about academia.SE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4374/moving-questions-to-academia-se